# Start again from latest schema with liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase 3.2.0 on [ORCID](https://github.com/ORCID/ORCID-Source), and finding it really useful.

We now have over 200 changeSets on top of the original schema.

These run many times during unit tests because we are using an in memory database (hsqldb).

I would like to 'reset' liquibase by making a new install.xml from the current schema, so that we do not have to run all the changeSets every time.

However, the production database (postgres) has a databasechangelog table with all the old changeSets, so it will try to apply the new install.xml.

How can I start again from a new install.xml without causing problems for production?

Will

Answer (score 1):

Restarting a changeLog from scratch is the same as adding liquibase to an existing project, which is [discussed in documentation here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html)

I generally recommend against resetting your changeLog, however, because normally the costs outweigh any benefits in performance. Your 200 changeSet changelog has been fully tested and you know it is correct whereas something regenerated manually or with generateChangeLog can easily have minor differences that can cause problems.

For existing databases, the startup cost of parsing the changelog file and comparing it to the contents of databasechangelog is very low, regardless of the number of changeSets.

For a new database, especially in-memory databases, DDL operations are generally very fast and the speed of going through 200 changeSets to build up your database will probably not be a lot different than building it up in 50 changeSets.

IF there are performance differences, what I've generally seen is that there are a few isolated changeSets that are the problem such as creating an index then dropping it then creating it again. I would recommend looking for any changeSets that may be a problem and carefully removing or combining them vs. a wholesale redo of the changelog.